# Correctly formatting reddit codeblocks in powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

So I have been learning PowerShell,  I sometimes ask questions on the PowerShell forum at Reddit but people often complain about my posts quality (lack of code blocks).

I really like that forum, I learn allot just from reading the posts but I sometimes want to post and also ask questions too, so I have endeavoured to write a PowerShell  program that will take a markdown file as input and correctly format the code blocks the way Reddit expects it to be.

The program should take any set of lines contained in three or more backticks, using the `-replace` operator, remove the backticks and prefix four spaces (`\s`) to each line.
so If I had a `InputExample.txt` that looks like this:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxx`
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
...
Get-Childitem -Path 'c:\temp\test.ps1'
Get-Childitem -Path 'c:\temp\test.ps1'
Get-Childitem -Path 'c:\temp\test.ps1'
...
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxx`
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
...
MouseGetPos, Xpos, Ypos
WinWait, %Window%
WinGetPos,,, Width, Height
MouseGetPos, X, Y
...
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
xxxxxxxxxx
...
Hello := "Hello World"
Test := Hello ~= "Hello" ? "Yes, Match!" (Word_Count := 2) : "No Match!"
OutputDebug, % "Test : "Test
OutputDebug, % "Word count is : "Word_Count
...
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxx`
...
Test : Yes, Match!2
Word count is : 2
...
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
```

please interpret the `...` as three backticks, I don't fully understand how to escape them in Markdown
The expected output should be:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxx`
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

    Get-Childitem -Path 'c:\temp\test.ps1'
    Get-Childitem -Path 'c:\temp\test.ps1'
    Get-Childitem -Path 'c:\temp\test.ps1'

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxx`
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

    MouseGetPos, Xpos, Ypos
    WinWait, %Window%
    WinGetPos,,, Width, Height
    MouseGetPos, X, Y

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
xxxxxxxxxx

    Hello := "Hello World"
    Test := Hello ~= "Hello" ? "Yes, Match!" (Word_Count := 2) : "No Match!"
    OutputDebug, % "Test : "Test
    OutputDebug, % "Word count is : "Word_Count

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxx`

    Test : Yes, Match!2
    Word count is : 2

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxx
`xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
```

My RegEx is knowledge is not much stronger than my PowerShell knowledge, I tred:

`````
$Myvar = Get-Content -path '.\InputExample.txt' -Raw
#`$Myvar -replace "^```\n..*````"            # Will not execute no matter what I try :/
`$Myvar -replace "^```\n(.*)```", "$1"       # Same issue as above
$Myvar -replace '`{3}(\r?\n)', '    $1    '  # This partially works
`````

I got close enough with the last attempt, I managed  to select all the code inside ```` ``` ```` (including the backticks themselves) but  attempting to prefix each line with a backspace with `'    $1    '` does not do what I am expecting.

Can someone help me with this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might find this easier using regex replacement with a [match evaluator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-replace(system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-matchevaluator)) a.k.a. [replacement with a script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#replacement-with-a-script-block), basically you can make your match evaluator replace the start of each line with 4 spaces for your capturing group `1`.

Assuming we have the provided example stored in the variable `$string` and we have used `-Raw` switch to read the file content:

```bash
$string = Get-Content path\to\file -Raw
```

In PowerShell 6+ you can do the following:

```bash
$string -replace '(?ms)^`{3}(\r?\n.+?\r?\n)^`{3}', {
    $_.Groups[1].Value -replace '(?m)^', '    '
}
```

And in Windows PowerShell 5.1 you need to call the API directly:

```bash
[regex]::Replace($string, '(?ms)^`{3}(\r?\n.+?\r?\n)^`{3}', {
    $args[0].Groups[1].Value -replace '(?m)^', '    ' })
```